# Can't read some attributes with SAX

Tags: java, sax, xml-parsing

I'm trying to parse that document with SAX:

```
<scxml version="1.0" initialstate="start" name="calc"> 
  <datamodel> 
      <data id="expr" expr="0" /> 
      <data id="res" expr="0" /> 
  </datamodel> 
  <state id="start"> 
      <transition event="OPER" target="opEntered" /> 
      <transition event="DIGIT" target="operand" /> 
  </state> 
  <state id="operand"> 
      <transition event="OPER" target="opEntered" /> 
      <transition event="DIGIT" /> 
  </state> 
</scxml>
```

I read all the attributes well, except "initialstate" and "name"...
I get the attributes with the startElement handler, but the size of the attribute list for scxml is zero. Why? How I can overcome that problem?

**Edit**:

```
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes){
  System.out.println(attributes.getValue("initialstate"));
  System.out.println(attributes.getValue("name")); 
}
```

that, when parsing the first tag, doesn't work (prints "null" two times). In fact,

```
attributes.getLength();
```

evaluates to zero.

Thanks

Comment: I guess some code would be welcome.

Comment: public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes) {
  System.out.println(attributes.getValue("initialstate"));
  System.out.println(attributes.getValue("name"));
}

That doesn't work when the first tag is parsed.

Comment: Are there any XML namespaces in the document?

Comment: this is the canonical example taken from the scxml standard, so... no, there aren't no xml namespaces. Are they relevant for my problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've got a full example working from [there](http://www.javabeat.net/tips/23-parsing-xml-documents-using-sax.html) and adapted it for your file:

```
public class SaxParserMain {

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws SAXException
     * @throws ParserConfigurationException
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException,
            IOException {
        SAXParser parser = SAXParserFactory.newInstance().newSAXParser();
        CustomHandler handler = new CustomHandler();
        parser.parse(new File("file/scxml.xml"), handler);
    }
}
```

and

```
public class CustomHandler extends DefaultHandler {

    @Override
    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes)
            throws SAXException {
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("<" + qName + "");
        if (attributes.getLength() == 0) {
            System.out.print(">");
        } else {
            System.out.print(" ");
            for (int index = 0; index < attributes.getLength(); index++) {
                System.out.print(attributes.getLocalName(index) + " => "
                        + attributes.getValue(index));
            }
            System.out.print(">");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException {
        System.out.print("\n</" + qName + ">");
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
<scxml version => 1.0initialstate => startname => calc>
<datamodel>
<data id => exprexpr => 0>
</data>
<data id => resexpr => 0>
</data>
</datamodel>
<state id => start>
<transition event => OPERtarget => opEntered>
</transition>
<transition event => DIGITtarget => operand>
</transition>
</state>
<state id => operand>
<transition event => OPERtarget => opEntered>
</transition>
<transition event => DIGIT>
</transition>
</state>
</scxml>
```

Comment: Uh, thanks, problem solved.
The problem is that sax uses always the same attributes instance, filling it everytime it raises an event. I've assumed that it was always a /different/ instance. Sigh! :)

Comment: Yeah, the javadoc says it: "atts - the attributes attached to the element. If there are no attributes, it shall be an empty Attributes object. **The value of this object after startElement returns is undefined**"

Answer (score 1):

`Attributes.getValue()` isn't as simple as it look. The [javadoc](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/xml/sax/Attributes.html#getValue%28java.lang.String%29) says:

> Look up an attribute's value by XML
>   qualified (prefixed) name.

So passing in just "initialstate" might not work if there are any namespace complications, since "initialstate" is not technically a qualified name.

I suggest having a play with the other methods on the `Attributes` class, such as `getValue(int)`, you might have more succes with those.

---

**edit**: Another possibility is that this invocation of `startElement` isn't referring to the element you think it is. Have you verified that the `localName` argument is indeed `scxml`, and not something else?

Comment: The problem is that the length of the attributes list is zero for the first tag...